# como hacer push a un array con elementos de un input

Tags: array, input

Quiero agregar elementos de un input a un array, pero cada vez que se hace `push`, el array se reinicia y no se van agregando los elementos.

Cuando lo imprimo se muestra nuevamente como un nuevo array:

```
function busca() {

      var _platillo = document.getElementById("platillo").value;
      var _precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;
      var tot=[]
      tot.push(_platillo+_precio);          
           document.getElementById('resultado').value= tot;
   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que sacar el array fuera de la función porque se esta inicializando cada vez que se llama la función `busca()`.

```
var tot=[];

function busca() {
      var _platillo = document.getElementById("platillo").value;
      var _precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;
      tot.push(_platillo+_precio);          
      document.getElementById('resultado').value= tot;
};
```